# Cannot reuse an 'ApiController' instance - Unity DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection) tutorial to use Unity dependency injection in WebAPI.

To avoid registering each type seperatly I used this setup

```
_container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

This works well for the first time but since the second one I get

> "Cannot reuse an 'ApiController' instance. 'ApiController' has to be constructed per incoming message. Check your custom 'IHttpControllerActivator' and make sure that it will not manufacture the same instance."

How do I reslove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the looks of it when you say `WithLifetime.ContainerControlled` it means you are asking Unity to register a Singleton instance (i.e. reuse the instance) which is what its complaining about.
You need to set a PerRequest lifetime manager